# Setting up live streaming radio station

Tags: javascript, jquery, live-streaming

My next challenge is to build a live streaming radio station.

I am familiar with `<audio>` element of HTML5 also I did a bit research on how other people implemented such a task.

All my founding were like 5 years old (listed below), so I think I might miss something,
or just people are not listening to online radio stations anymore?!

Set up [Html5 Audio Radio Player](https://dev.opera.com/articles/html5-audio-radio-player/).

The tutorial uses jPlayer (a jQuery library) and Icecast (a free server for streaming multimedia) but the article is 7 years old.

Is anybody have a better clue of how to start tackling this ?

Comment: There is a javascript/node library for icecast streams here https://www.npmjs.com/package/icecast

Comment: This other question looks similar  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751390/what-is-the-best-way-to-stream-audio-to-the-browser-chunk-by-chunk-with-javacr/74768868#74768868

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you want, but I did this a couple years ago with icecast and it worked fine and wasn't too hard, nor too inflexible to mold into modern webpages.  It gave me a live audio stream in the proper format (m3u i think).  As far as how you present that stream, that'll be more web-design oriented, but you can just open that link that comes from icecast in a webserver so it's not like you're trying to make a square peg fit in a round hole, it's not an obscure standard whatever icecast is spitting out.

I would suggest getting icecast set up and getting a stream working and then working through the web player aspect after that.  Maybe there's something newer than icecast, but it does its job fine.

Comment: Hi, can u please explain or tell me step by step or checklist to start the setup? @chairmanmow

Comment: @BriantStevanus Been a while since I did this but happy to help if you're stuck, but to start official docs are here https://www.icecast.org/docs/icecast-trunk/basic_setup/ ...  The basic mechanics are you install/run icecast on server and there will be a web server running on port 8000 (default) where you can configure/see some things - then on another computer where you're streaming from you'd have a client that pipes your audio to the server, I used 'butt' on mac, there are others for other OS's I believe.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for the volume radio mute and all the other but live from your pc idk i am not sure if this code is well optimaized i didnt try because it works

```js
const radio = document.getElementById("radiolink"); //Your radio/audio id:
const playbtn = document.getElementById("playbtn"); //play btn id:
const mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn"); //mutebtn id:
let volumei = document.getElementById("audioslide"); //the voleme input slider:
let volume ; //a volume variable:
let playing = false; //variable if its playing or not:
let mute = false; //variable if its mute or not:

playbtn.onclick = function(){
    playing = !playing; //changes the variable to oposite

   if(playing == true){
    radio.play();
    console.log(playing);
    playbtn.className = "fa-solid fa-pause"
   }
   else if(playing == false){
    radio.pause();
    playbtn.className = "fa-solid fa-play"
    playing = false;
    
   }
   else{
    console.log('error');
   }
   }


mutebtn.onclick = function(){
    mute = !mute //changes the variable to oposite
   }


setInterval(volumef, 100); //runs volumef function  every 100ms

function volumef(){
    volume = volumei.value / 10 //take the data from the volume slider thats from 1 to 10 and divides by ten to get the radio ones from 0.0 to 1.0

    console.log(volume);
    

    if(volume > 0 && !mute ){
        mutebtn.className = "fa-solid fa-volume-high"
        radio.volume = volume; //it will make the volume the value of the volume thats at the start of this function
    
    }
    else if(volume == 0 || mute == true){
        mutebtn.className = "fa-solid fa-volume-off"
        radio.volume = 0; //it will set the radio volume to 0
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="put your font awesome link from their website for the icons to work" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


        <div id="radio">
          
            <button id="playbtn" class="fa-solid fa-play "></button>

            <button id="mutebtn" class="fa-solid fa-volume-high"></button>

            <audio  id="radiolink">
                <source src="your radio link example: http://zuicast.digitalag.ro:9420/zu">
              </audio>

             <div id="audioslider">
                <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="10" id="audioslide">
             </div> 
        </div>

      
     
    
    <script src="radio.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35621576)