# What is the best way to stream audio to the browser, chunk by chunk, with javacript

Tags: javascript, node.js, streaming, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I'm trying to make an internet radio station and I would like to frequently change songs and overlay sound freely. I'd like to rate-limit the audio  so the feed can be altered before its sent out. I'd also like to serve continuous content if that is possible

So far, we have a close to successful attempt with websockets, but the quality is a bit messy

Here's the code:
server.js

```js
const express     = require('express');
const app         = express()
const http        = require('http')
const server      = http.createServer(app)
const { Server }  = require("socket.io")
const io          = new Server(server)
const fs          = require('fs')

const SRC_PATH      = 'src.wav'
const PACKET_SIZE   = 6400
let   PACKET = 0

function getpacket(socket){
    const file_descriptor     = fs.openSync(SRC_PATH, 'r', null)
    const read_offset         = PACKET * PACKET_SIZE
    const buffer              = Buffer.alloc(PACKET_SIZE)
    const buffer_write_offset = 0
    const num_bytes_to_read   = PACKET_SIZE
    const num_bytes_read      = fs.readSync(file_descriptor, buffer, buffer_write_offset, num_bytes_to_read, read_offset)
    fs.closeSync(file_descriptor)
    console.log(`Sending packet ${PACKET}`)
    socket.emit("data", buffer)
    PACKET++
}

app.use('/', express.static('.'))

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("connected...")
    socket.on("get", ()=>{getpacket(socket)})
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
})
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div onclick="listen()">Click to Listen</div>

    <script>
    const socketio     = io()
    const SAMPLE_RATE  = 32000 // samples/second
    
    async function listen(){
        // Set up the new audio context
        const audioContext = new AudioContext()

        socketio.once("data", (arrayBuff)=>{
            const buffer = new Uint8Array(arrayBuff)
            addTobuffer(buffer, audioContext)
        })

        requestData()
    }

    function requestData(){
        socketio.emit("get")
    }

    async function addTobuffer(data, audioContext){
        // Set up the new audio source
        const audioSource  = await audioContext.createBufferSource()
        // create audio buffer from data,
        const audioBuffer  = await createAudioBuffer(audioContext,data) 
        // Asign the data buffer to the audioSource
        audioSource.buffer = audioBuffer
        // Connect the audio source to the audio context
        audioSource.connect(audioContext.destination)

        audioSource.start(0)
        // wait until just before the end and then get more data
        const packetLength    = (data.length/SAMPLE_RATE)*1000-10
        await new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve,packetLength))

        socketio.once("data", (arrayBuff)=>{
            const buffer = new Uint8Array(arrayBuff)
            addTobuffer(buffer, audioContext)
        })
        requestData()
    }

    async function createAudioBuffer(audioContext,data){
        /* uint8 pcm to float */
        const number_of_channels = 1
        const number_of_bytes    = data.length
        const audioBuffer        = audioContext.createBuffer(number_of_channels, number_of_bytes, SAMPLE_RATE)
        const nowBuffering       = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0)
        for (let index=0; index<number_of_bytes;index++){
            const thirtytwofloat = new Float32Array(1)
            thirtytwofloat[0]    = (data[index]-(255/2))/255
            nowBuffering[index]  = thirtytwofloat[0]
        }
        return audioBuffer
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And to generate the strangely formatted PCM WAV:

```bash
ffmpeg -i src.mp3 -ar 32000 -ac 1 -acodec pcm_u8 src.wav
```

Is there a way to get cleaner audio output?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so it looks like many radio stations like [Today's Hits](https://rfcmedia.streamguys1.com/MusicPulse.mp3) (which can be found in the [howler.js radio example](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/blob/master/examples/radio/radio.js)), stream audio by using the [live streaming standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Live_streaming_web_audio_and_video)

First they send an http message "content-type: audio/mpeg", as well as a few other messages like [Transfer-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) to signal the browser that a stream is coming and to keep the connection to the server. We can see the http messages if we look at the network tab of the [developers console](https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/) on safari and examine the requests

According to [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Live_streaming_web_audio_and_video#audio_streaming_file_formats) there are a handful of formats that are standardized for streaming, wav doesn't look to be one of them at the moment, but mp3 is though

Here's a working example...
server.js

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')
const schedule     = require('node-schedule')
const express      = require('express')
const http         = require("http")
const fs           = require('fs')

const app          = express()

const SAMPLE_SIZE = 32000                         // samples/sec
const PACKET_SIZE = SAMPLE_SIZE                   // 1 second worth of data
const UPDATE_TIME = '* * * * * *'                 // every second
const PATH        = "./src.mp3"
let   PACKET_NUM  = 0
const eventEmitter= new EventEmitter ()

async function getpacket(req,res){
  const file_descriptor     = fs.openSync(PATH, 'r', null)
  const read_offset         = PACKET_NUM * PACKET_SIZE
  const buffer              = Buffer.alloc(PACKET_SIZE)
  const buffer_write_offset = 0
  const num_bytes_to_read   = PACKET_SIZE
  const num_bytes_read      = fs.readSync(file_descriptor, buffer, buffer_write_offset, num_bytes_to_read, read_offset)
  fs.closeSync(file_descriptor)
  console.log(`Sending packet ${PACKET_NUM} to ${req.socket.remoteAddress}`) // safari sometimes requests two streams at the same time
  res.write(buffer)
}

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile("index.html",{root: '.'})
})

app.get("/src.mp3", async (req,res)=>{
    res.writeHead(200,"OK",{"Content-Type":"audio/mpeg"})

    const updateHandler = () =>{ getpacket(req,res) }
    eventEmitter.on("update", updateHandler) // On update event, send another packet

    req.socket.on("close",()=>{
      eventEmitter.removeListener("update",updateHandler)
      console.log(`Client ${req.socket.remoteAddress} disconected from server`)
    })
})

// This creates a schedule to make an update event on every second
schedule.scheduleJob(UPDATE_TIME, function(){
  PACKET_NUM+=1
  eventEmitter.emit("update")
})

const server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(3000)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <audio controls id="music"></audio>

    <div onclick="listen()">Click to Listen</div>
    <div onclick="stop()">Click to Stop</div>

    <script>    
    async function listen(){
       let music = document.getElementById('music')
       music.src="/src.mp3"
       music.play()
    }

    async function stop(){
       let music = document.getElementById('music')
       music.pause()
       music.src=""
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And to generate the mp3 file from the wav file

```bash
ffmpeg -i src.wav -ab 128k src.mp3
```

If server.js is running on your machine you can go to http://localhost:3000/src.mp3 to see the live stream, and http://localhost:3000/ to see the example of it's support in the browser

It is possible to update src.mp3 live with ffmpeg

### Packages and helpful resources

- EventEmitter is a default node package
- [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)
- [crontab-style string](https://crontab.guru/)
- [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)
- [http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http)
- fs is default node package
- [html lock screen player metadata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API)

### Some ffmpeg insights for live editing

- [ffmpeg pipe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe)
- [ffmpeg concat wavs](https://superuser.com/questions/587511/concatenate-multiple-wav-files-using-single-command-without-extra-file)
- [overlay wav files at position](https://superuser.com/questions/1509582/ffmpeg-merge-two-audio-file-with-defined-overlapping-time)
- [mixing wav files with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498539/how-to-overlay-downmix-two-audio-files-using-ffmpeg)